# PHP - search / filter a multidimentional array by string(s)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$testarray = array(
    array(
        'First name' => 'Johnny',
        'Last name' => 'Milthers',
        'Age' => '24'
    ),
    array(
        'First name' => 'Toby',
        'Last name' => 'Thomson',
        'Age' => '25'), 
    ),
    array(
        'First name' => 'Jack',
        'Last name' => 'Johnson',
        'Age' => '25'),
    );
```

How do i pass search strings such as 'John', to then have the array $testarray contain only the first and last array?.

I need to pass a search term, that return the whole subarray if any of the keys values contain that string.

also if i pass "Jack Johnson", $testarray should contain only the last array.

- Is this possible, or am i going about it the wrong way? 
  how do normal search result work for databases work?

I have been looking at a lot of stack overflow pages (and PHP manual + google), but nothing helped me out, if im posting something that already has an answer, please comment me the link.

Thank you soo much!

Comment: The array you give is full of syntax errors

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way of doing it, bare in mind it will only work if the search arrays are nested directly in the outer search array.

```
function search_array($text, $array) {
    return array_filter($array, function($a) use($text){

       return stristr(implode(" ", $a), $text);

    });
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/09e1187ccedba0804de5d797c350e218b05951cd

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but this should work...

```
function find_in_array($search, $testarray) {
  $pattern = '*'.$search.'*';
  $array = array_filter($testarray, function($entry) use ($pattern) {
    foreach($entry as $key=>$value) {
      if (fnmatch($pattern, $value)) return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
  return $array;
 }
```

Comment: i tried this and it worked well, except there was an issue (for me) that there is a limit to the number of characters you can test against in fnmatch... so if you're trying to search an array item with more than 260 characters it throws an error.